# Pushing characters in char array to index 0

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I'm trying to build a string from f, being split at whitespace and read it into a struct.
f is the char array I'm iterating over.

I then copy the contents from tmp into ra1.callsign, and essentially empty the tmp char array.

What I want to do is have the the tmp variable start building from index 0 again, so that when I try to strcpy the second time round all the characters in tmp start from index 0.
The way I have it now, when it tries the line: strcpy(ra1.location, tmp) it doesn't copy anything, I think this is because at that point the first character in tmp doesn't appear until some time down the array.

```
char c;
char tmp[1000];

for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    c = f[i];

    if (c != ' ') {
        tmp[i] = c; //build string to be added
    }

    //add string to data structure
    if (c == ' ') {
        if (addTo == CALLSIGN) {
            strncpy(ra1.callsign, tmp, strlen(tmp));
            memset(tmp, '\0', strlen(tmp));
        }

        if (addTo == LOCATION) {
            strcpy(ra1.location, tmp);
        }

        ++addTo;
    }
}
```

Hope this is clear enough, thanks.

Comment: No, it is not clear enough.

Comment: after this line: memset(tmp, '\0', strlen(tmp)); where I empty the string, the loop continues building the string again, preferably I'd like a function that pushes all the characters in the array back to index 0 right before this line: strcpy(ra1.location, tmp);

Comment: memmove() does what you ask, assuming I have a prayer of getting it right. It can be used to shift the position of a substring to another position, overwriting the characters already there.  It does nothing to the source memory, unless there is overlap, which it handles correctly. The source always overwrites the destination.

Answer (score 1):

You left out quite a few details in your code and I have made a number of assumptions.

So, using the assumptions that I have made (which you can see in the code below), I believe that this will do what you are trying to accomplish.  There are much easier and cleaner ways to do this, but I am hoping that you can get a clear understanding of how it would work with your code.

I have basically added a terminating null character where it is required so the `strlen()` function will work correctly and utilized an extra variable called `cur_size` which can be used as an offset based on the current index `i`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CALLSIGN    3U
#define LOCATION    5U

#define ARRAY_SIZE   50U

typedef struct
{
    char callsign[ARRAY_SIZE];
    char location[ARRAY_SIZE];
} MyStruct;

MyStruct ra1 = { .callsign = {0}, .location = {0} };
char f[] = "This is my character array. Let's see what happens.";

int main (void)
{
    char c;
    char tmp[ARRAY_SIZE];
    unsigned char addTo = 0;
    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char cur_size = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(f); ++i)
    {
        c = f[i];
        if(c != ' ')
        {
            tmp[i - cur_size] = c; //build string to be added
        }

        //add string to data structure
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            tmp[i - cur_size] = '\0';  /* YOU NEED THIS FOR strlen(tmp) to work */
            cur_size = i + 1;
            if(addTo == CALLSIGN)
            {
                strncpy(ra1.callsign, tmp, strlen(tmp));
                //memset(tmp, '\0', strlen(tmp));
            }
            else if (addTo == LOCATION)
            {
                strncpy(ra1.location, tmp, strlen(tmp));
            }

            ++addTo;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", ra1.callsign[i]);
    }
    printf("\r\n");

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", ra1.location[i]);
    }
    printf("\r\n");

    return 0;
}
```